# Set autoindent in VIM's .exrc

Tags: vim

I am following [this tutorial](http://kb.iu.edu/data/afcw.html) to set the autoindent for all vi files. So I created a file .exrc in the home directory (which require me to sudo), but upon saving it it kept saying the file is read only and require a "!" to override. So I tried !ZZ, ZZ!, :!ZZ but all doesn't work.

How to I set the autoindent to vi?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a `.vimrc` file.
2. It should go into *your* "home" directory. Assuming you are on a Linux box, *your* "home" directory should be `/home/username`. No auth problem if you do things correctly.

   Your "home" directory is often called `~` or `$HOME`, so your `.vimrc`'s path can be written `~/.vimrc`, `$HOME/.vimrc` or `/home/username/.vimrc`. Same deal with the `~/.vim/` directory that you must create manually if you want to install colorschemes or plugins.
3. Don't use `set autoindent`. Instead, add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

   ```
   filetype plugin indent on
   ```
4. Make sure you are running a proper Vim build. The default Vim on most UNIXes is a "small" or "tiny" build not suitable for "serious" usage. `vim-gtk` is one such "proper" Vim.
5. Read about these subjects:

   ```
   :h :filetype
   :h vimrc-intro
   ```

Comment: What is the reason not to use `set autoindent`?

Comment: Because it's dumb and too generic. Using a filetype-specific indent is generally better.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to romainl's reply, I want to add that "vi" and "Vim" are similar, but not the same (Vim is vastly more powerful than plain vi). That is why romainl said to use `~/.vimrc` instead of `~/.exrc`.  (Vim will read the latter if the former doesn't exist, for compatibility reasons, but there are reasons to always use `~/.vimrc` which I won't go into.)

The other thing you should do, since you are clearly so new to Vim, is to run "`vimtutor`".